# Is it possible to edit an html file through a javascript based app?

Tags: javascript, html

Good day! I want to apologize for the bad title, but I am not really sure how to express my question in a short manner.

Consider the following situation: You have an html form (regardless with what fields) and you have some empty spaces. For example consider it has a space for text and a space for receiver. They are both already styled with css, but the inner html is left empty.

My question is the following: Is it possible to create a program with JavaScript which will edit (rather set) the inner html of the file to something and create a new file containing it.

My research so far hasn't been too successful, and I am starting to think that it is not possible (because you can't directly read files from JavaScript) So I decided to ask here as a last resort.

Comment: It is possible to inject (editing) HTML attribute via Javascript.

Comment: What do you want to do **after** the html has been edited.  (Save it locally, upload it to a server, or ?)

Comment: I want to store it locally. It will at some point be uploaded (probably) but the main idea is to create a new html doc with edited html of elements.

Comment: Have you seen http://jsfiddle.net or http://c9.io ? Javascript programming editors clearly exist and can save the edited programs, but they have to be saved by using AJAX to transmit the text of the programming code back to the server and save it at the server.  It can then be downloaded back to a workstation.  But as Anar explains below, Javascript is not designed to save files directly at the user's location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, for security reasons, Javascript cannot access your file system and this is by design. Hence, you cannot read or change files using Javascript or any client based programming language. You need server side languages like PHP, C# to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you. In that case server side it is.

Comment: Not technically. There is the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), but I don't think this is what the OP is asking for, since this is a sandboxed filesystem.